# compiler error, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am implementing an octree tree in c++ using visual studio.
When i call the build function i get this error:

> error C2664: 'BuildTree' : cannot
>   convert parameter 5 from
>   'overloaded-function' to 'int' 1

this is the line that i get the error:

```
BuildTree(parent, 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, length , maxLevel,0, 0.25);
```

and the function is this:

```
treeNode * BuildTree( treeNode * parent, float xx , float yy, float zz , int length ,int maxLevel,int val,float threshold)
```

Can anyone help me to correct this error?

Comment: post code where you declare length/maxLevel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably a function named `length` accessible in the current scope when you call the `BuildTree` function.

Answer (score 1):

Is `length` a variable or a function name? Did you mean to call `length()`?

Comment: I can't count, I meant `length`